# How can I clone a private GitLab repository from Ubuntu command line using GitHub authentication?

Tags: github, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04, gitlab-ci-runner

I can clone a private GitLab repository using the following command

`git clone https://UserName:Password@URL/repository.git`

But I need to clone the same private repo in GitLab server using GitHub login credentials. Have any idea?

Comment: Gitlab and GitHub have separate credentials.

Comment: But GitLab allows GitHub credentials to login